# Applescript add a list of directories to finder sidebar favorites

Tags: macos, applescript, sidebar, finder

Every time I disconnect from my network drive I loose a bunch of shortcuts to directories that I have setup in the finder sidebar/favorites list.

Is it possible to write an AppleScript (with predefined directories) to restore these back into the sidebar? There's over 12 folders I often have in the sidebar and it's a huge pain to have to re-add each time I restart.

(currently running macOS Sierra)

Thanks!

Comment: Mark, how did you get on with the solutions that were provided for you ?

Answer (score 1):

This following solution works for volumes and folders located in these volumes.  I simply selected all of my mounted volumes and folders, and created aliases.  From there I selected all of those aliases and created a new folder containing them all.  From there, all I did was add that folder to the favorites side bar in Finder.  After a reboot, I did not lose my new created favorites folder and was able to remount everything.

[image]